# Why is the eccentricity of a catenary equal to sqrt(2)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

I understand that eccentricity defines how circular a conic section is... but a catenary isn't a conic section - so why is its eccentricity equal to that of a rectangular hyperbola: $\sqrt 2$ ?  How does it have an eccentricity in the first place? 
 Are there other figures that aren't conics that still has an eccentricity?

Comment: Where did you read about this eccentricity?

Comment: I read about this eccentricity here: https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/formulas/Catenary+curve